# Preview and push stream are all black

Tags: zegocloud

I use ZEGOCLOUD express SDK. After accessing beauty through custom pre-processing, the preview and push stream are all black.

code:

```java
express.enableCustomVideoProcessing( enable: true, config, ZegoPublishChannel.MAIN);
express.setCustomVideoProcessHandler(new IZegoCustomVideoProcessHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onStart (ZegoPublishChannel channel) {
        Log_i(tag:"ZEGOCLOUD", msg:"[Express] [onStart]");
        effects.initEnv(720, 1280);
    }

    @override
    public void onStop(ZegoPublishChannel channel) {
        Log_i(tag:"ZEGOCLOUD", msg:"[Express] [onStop]");
        effects.uninitEnv();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCapturedUnprocessedTextureData(int textureID, int width, int height, Long referenceTimeMillisecond, ZegoPublishChannel channel) {
        Log.i( tag: "ZEGOCLOUD". msg: "[Exoress] [onCapturedUnprocessedTextureData] textureID:" + textureID + "width:" + width + "height: " + height + ", ts:" + referenceTimeMillisecond);

        effectsVideoFrameParam.width = width;
        effectsVideoFrameParam.height = height;


        int processedTextureID = effects.processTexture(textureID, effectsVideoFrameParam);

        express.sendCustomVideoProcessedTextureData(processedTextureID, width, height, referenceTimeMillisecond);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effects initialization is called in `onStart`, but there is a problem with the `glcontext` obtained here, and then beautify in `onCapturedUnprocessedTextureData`, because the `glcontext` is wrong, it reads black.

So you need to move `effects.initEnv()` to the `onCapturedUnprocessedTextureData` method.

like it:

```java
express.enableCustomVideoProcessing( enable: true, config, ZegoPublishChannel.MAIN);
express.setCustomVideoProcessHandler(new IZegoCustomVideoProcessHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onStart (ZegoPublishChannel channel) {
        Log_i(tag:"ZEGOCLOUD", msg:"[Express] [onStart]");
    }

    @override
    public void onStop(ZegoPublishChannel channel) {
        Log_i(tag:"ZEGOCLOUD", msg:"[Express] [onStop]");
        effects.uninitEnv();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCapturedUnprocessedTextureData(int textureID, int width, int height, Long referenceTimeMillisecond, ZegoPublishChannel channel) {
        Log.i( tag: "ZEGOCLOUD". msg: "[Exoress] [onCapturedUnprocessedTextureData] textureID:" + textureID + "width:" + width + "height: " + height + ", ts:" + referenceTimeMillisecond);
        
        effects.initEnv(720, 1280);

        effectsVideoFrameParam.width = width;
        effectsVideoFrameParam.height = height;


        int processedTextureID = effects.processTexture(textureID, effectsVideoFrameParam);

        express.sendCustomVideoProcessedTextureData(processedTextureID, width, height, referenceTimeMillisecond);
    }
});
```